# Page loader working fine on local host .. but on server never fadeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<style>
    .bg {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
    }

    .loader {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background: url('images/loader.gif');
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        top: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        margin-top: -21px;
    }
</style>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
    $(".bg").fadeOut('slow');
})
</script>
```

html code is

```
<div class="bg">
    <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

it is a page loader .when we open a new page it shows a gif image ..this code works fine on localhost ...but when i put it on server the gif image never goes even after loading of page..

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: there is no error .. the gif is on my main page.. eve after loading ... and i dont know about console ???

Comment: hard to tell. Try with `$(window).on('load', function(){...}` Here's a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nh9zjmzh/

Answer (score 0):

One of my assumptions might be that your .gif is not found

`background: url('images/loader.gif');`

Cuz from my experience I had to use `asset-url` / `url-path` or give a full path towards the asset.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare all the required css and script codes inside the head tag of your index.html. You can follow my code given below:

```
**index.html**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script>
    //preloader
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        setTimeout("myFunction()", 8000);
</script>
<style>
 #loading {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background: rgb(24, 32, 39) url("./loading.gif") no-repeat center;
            z-index: 99999;

        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Pre loader-->
    <div id="loading" style="visibility: visible;">
    </div>
</body>
```